# Laravel: return JSON model with relation

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to query a model with a relation.

My method:

```
public function getLabel($layerId)
{

    $labelGroups = Forum_label_group::
        join('forum_layer_to_labels', function ($join) use ($layerId) {
            $join->on('forum_layer_to_labels.layerId', '=', 'forum_label_groups.id');
        })->with('labels')->get()->toJson();

    return $labelGroups;
}
```

The output:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Demogruppe","description":"bla","required":1,"created_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","updated_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","labelGroupId":2,"layerId":2,"labels":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Demogruppe 2","description":"bla 2","required":0,"created_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","updated_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","labelGroupId":2,"layerId":3,"labels":[]}]
```

As you can see, the label relation is empty.

Now I'm trying to query a single model instead off all:

```
public function getLabel($layerId)
{
    return Forum_label_group::with('labels')->first()->toJson();
}
```

the new output:

```
"{"id":2,"name":"Demogruppe","description":"bla","required":1,"created_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","updated_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:27","labels":[{"id":5,"title":"Demo rot","name":"demo-rot","typeId":3,"groupId":2,"created_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:47","updated_at":"2016-10-22 12:29:47"},{"id":6,"title":"Demoblau","name":"demoblau","typeId":1,"groupId":2,"created_at":"2016-10-22 12:30:03","updated_at":"2016-10-22 12:30:03"}]}"
```

And as you can see now, everything is fine. The whole relation exists. Is there a problem with the initial query? The relation seems to be ok.

Comment: Any reason you're using `::with('labels')` and `->with('labels')` in the same eloquent statement?

Comment: Whoops, you're right! The `::with('labels')` was an obsolete debugging test. I've edited the question.

Comment: No worries; I don't think it affects anything really, but it was certainly odd to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course it was an small issue ;)

I forgot to add a `select()` on my query. The original `id` has been overwritten by the `join()`. So the method tried to query an `labelGroup` that doesn't exist.

The correct query:

```
public function getLabel($layerId)
    {
        $labelGroups = Forum_label_group::
            join('forum_layer_to_labels', function ($join) use ($layerId) {
                $join->on('forum_layer_to_labels.layerId', '=', 'forum_label_groups.id');
            })->select('forum_label_groups.*')->with('labels')
            ->get();

        return $labelGroups;
    }
```